# How does this simplification of this derivative work?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So there is a simplification I don't understand it goes like this:

\begin{alignat}{2}
&\text{Original equation:}\qquad 2\frac{dr}{dt}\frac{d\theta}{dt}+r\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}&=0\\
&\text{Simplification:}\qquad\frac{1}{2r}\frac{d}{dt}\left(r^{2}\left(\frac{d\theta}{dt}\right)\right)&=0
\end{alignat}

The reason why I don't understand it:
if I try to differentiate the simplification I won't get the original equation.
When I differentiate it I get:
$$\frac{1}{2r}\left(2r\left(\frac{d\theta}{dt}\right)+r^2\left(\frac{d^2\theta}{dt}\right)\right)$$
I'm just using the product rule. Could someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong. It would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You applied the product rule incorrectly. You should have
$$
(uv)'=u'v+uv'
$$
where $u=r^2$ and $v=d\theta/dt$.

Note that
$$
u'=2r r'\quad v'=\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}
$$
where $\displaystyle(\cdot)'=\frac{d(\cdot)}{dt}$.

---

Notes.

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2r}\frac{d}{dt}\left(r^{2}\left(\frac{d\theta}{dt}\right)\right)
&=\frac{1}{2r}(2r\frac{dr}{dt}\frac{d\theta}{dt}+r^2\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2})\\
&=\frac{dr}{dt}\frac{d\theta}{dt}+\frac{r}{2}\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much, I totally forgot that $(\cdot)^{\prime}=\frac{d(\cdot)}{d t}$, thanks

Comment: @TheCreator: you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Careful, $r$ is also a function of $t$, so you should have:
$$\frac{1}{2r}\frac{d}{dt}\left(r^{2}\left(\frac{d\theta}{dt}\right)\right) = \frac{1}{2r}\left(2r\frac{dr}{dt}\frac{d\theta}{dt} + r^{2}\frac{d^{2}\theta}{dt^2}\right) = \frac{dr}{dt}\frac{d\theta}{dt} + \frac{r}{2}\frac{d^{2}\theta}{dt^2}.$$  This gives us $$\frac{dr}{dt}\frac{d\theta}{dt} + \frac{r}{2}\frac{d^{2}\theta}{dt^2}=0,$$ which upon multiplying by $2$ gives us $$2\frac{dr}{dt} \frac{d\theta}{dt} + r\frac{d^{2}\theta}{dt^{2}} = 0.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I really appreciate it